# How to route traffic through different proxy servers based on destination

Tags: iptables, proxy, route, socks

### Background

I work on a corporate network that is behind a proxy server.  I also work with some remote sites that I am able to access via a bastion / jump host ssh proxy.

In my `~/.ssh/config` I have a proxy configuration for my SSH tunnels that allows the jumping through our bastion hosts in order to reach the remote labs

```
Host *.remoteLab1
    ProxyCommand ssh -l USERNAME BASTIONHOST1 nc %h %p

Host *.remoteLab2
    ProxyCommand ssh -l USERNAME BASTIONHOST2 nc %h %p
```

*I use both OSX and Linux so I assume the commands are more or less the same*

### Current Solution

My current solution is less than ideal.  I basically make a socks connection to one of the remote labs such as:

`ssh -D 1080 remoteLab1`

`ssh -D 1081 remoteLab2`

Then in both `realvnc` and `chrome` I change the proxy server to `localhost:1080 / localhost:1081`.  In chrome I have a plugin that allows me to do this and in VNC its manual.

As both of these remote labs have a unique domain I was wondering if there is an easier way playing with routing tables to send all traffic through these socks proxies based on ip address

### Requested Solution

**GIVEN:** A socks5 tunnel is open on port `1080`

**GIVEN:** A socks5 tunnel is open on port `1081`

**Requirements**

- addresses of `domain1.org` go through `1080`
- addresses of `domain2.org` go through `1081`
- fall through case - everything else goes through standard proxy server

**Nice-to-have's**

- The solution is not permanent - it is enabled by a script in conjunction with turning on one of the socks tunnels

*Is it possible to also map specific ip addresses as opposed to domains through one of the proxy servers*

#### Ideas

I'm not really sure at all where to start with all of this.  One solution I saw somewhere was to use a `proxy.pac` however the corporate network already has a `proxy.pac` and I wasn't sure if there is a way to do a fall-through `pac` where if not in my custom `.pac` then use the settings in the corporate `.pac`

Using the `iptables` or `route` command - however both of those are a little out of my knowledge zone

Setting up local loopbacks or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend changing your `ProxyCommand` from using `nc` to use `-W`. For example:

```
ProxyCommand ssh -l USERNAME BASTIONHOST1 -W %h:%p
```

That has fewer requirements for the bastion host, so it is less likely to break in case the administrator decides to change how the bastion host is configured.

I don't think there is any way to fall through between different pac files. But you can more or less just concatenate the two pac files - with one minor caveat. The entry point would exist in both files. You would need to rename the entry point in the original pac file and in your own additions you can make calls to the renamed version of the function.

Historically the entry point was a function named FindProxyForURL. Some newer browsers have extensions which are activated by using a differently named entry point.

Comment: Will this work for system processes as well or just browsers?

Comment: @Jeef It will work for anything supporting a proxy script. Some desktop environments have a single proxy configuration which is shared across all programs in that desktop environment such that changing the setting from one of the programs affects all of them.